# Proof of method for finding number of orbits

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$ acting on a set $S$. Prove that the number of orbits is $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n}{\#\mathrm{fix}\, g^{n/d}\cdot\phi(d)}$$

I have already shown that

1. the number of generators of $Z_n$ is $\phi(n)$
2. if there are positive integers satisfying $dk=n$, there exists a subgroup of $Z_n$ of order $d$ generated by $[k]$.
3. if there is a cyclic group $G$ operating on a set $S$ and $g_1$ and $g_2$ generate $G$ then $\#\mathrm{fix}\, g_1=\#\mathrm{fix}\, g_2$.

I have no idea how to put these together to show the identity above though. Any help would be great, thank you in advance!

Note that G is the disjoint union of the sets
$G_d$ = {g ∈ G | order g = d} = {g ∈ G | g generates the unique subgroup of order d}, where d ranges over all positive divisors of n.

Comment: have you checked the burnside lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma?